# HTML special character decoding

Tags: java, android, character-encoding

Using Java on Android I'm struggling to convert a couple of html special characters.

So far I've tried:

```
String myString = "%A32.00%20per%20month%B3";

Html.fromHtml(myString).toString(); => %A32.00%20per%20month%B3
URLDecoder.decode(myString) => �2.00 per month�
URLDecoder.decode(myString, "UTF-8") => �2.00 per month�
URLDecoder.decode(myString, "ASCII") => �2.00 per month�
org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(myString) => %A32.00%20per%20month%B3
```

The correct output should be => £2.00 per month³

Comment: Are you sure `URLDecoder.decode(myString, "UTF-8")` doesn't do the correct decoding but your output just can't display the `£` and `³` characters?

Comment: Apache commons StringEscapeUtils escapes/unescapes Html, which is not what you need here. Eg. £2.00 per month³ <-> &pound;2.00 per month&sup3;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your string is encoded in `ISO-8859-1`, so ASCII and UTF-8 won't work.

```
String myString = "%A32.00%20per%20month%B3";
URLDecoder.decode(myString, "ISO-8859-1");
// output: £2.00 per month³
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String before = "£2.00 per month³";
    String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(before, "UTF-8");
    String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(encoded, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(encoded);
    System.out.println(decoded);
}
```

In output I get:

```
%C2%A32.00+per+month%C2%B3
£2.00 per month³
```

Are you sure that `%A32.00%20per%20month%B3` is correct?

Comment: Spot on it was the input string (from a 3rd party webservice) that seems to have incorrectly encoded the string. When you add %C2 infront of the symbols it works correctly. Thanks